# Need help for a code to communicate between separate winform applications in C# over intranet:)

Tags: c#, winforms, networking, client-server

Can anyone help me with a coded example or any code to communicate between two separate application for multiple purposes like
i)   Find server application on the intranet from a client application running as client
ii)  Checking client or server is active from other side application
iii) Communication data or objects to the client or server from other side

I am using C# winforms and new to network applications so i need help.I preferred to ask this question here because i find more helpful links to help or guides than searching them over internet.

Comment: Do you want an example you won't understand, or do you want to learn something?

Comment: The WCF Developer Center is at http://msdn.microsoft.com/wcf/.

Comment: dear i want an example i am good at understanding code than reading books to understand them thats why i asked for that

Comment: but i do appriciate your advice :)

Answer (score 0):

I agree that this is too big a subject for one question.  However, to point you in the right direction, research WCF at the MSDN web site.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do a search for ".Net Remoting" which is another way for .Net processes to communicate with each other by name over a network (or same machine).

Answer (score 0):

Or you could go the Socket route and do something like multicast